# Update date propertie when hibernate decides to UPDATE an object

Tags: java, hibernate

we know that when you update an object doing session.update(obj) in hibernate, it will check if this one changed and will decide to update or not, the thing is that i want to update another colum named UPDATED_AT (BD) or propertie in my object in the case that hibernate decides to Update this object.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: We do this through a database trigger.  I'm not sure if there is a configuration in hibernate to do this or not.  Although, I would be a bit surprised if there wasn't a way to do this in hibernate.

Comment: Look for documentation on interceptors.

Comment: I know that it can be done with a trigger thanks hooknc, but i was looking for a way to do this with hibernate, so ill take a look on interceptors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [interceptor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/events.html) for this.

Interceptors are event listeners that Hibernate will invoke for certain events like when an object is loaded or when it's saved.

`onSave` is called before the object is actually saved and you get a list of all properties that will be persisted, so you can modify them before the `UPDATE` is sent to the database.

Comment: This seems to be helpfull, i will update the answer when i make it work, thanks :)

Comment: I have a question, my interceptor is not working when i use session.getCurrentSession(), please note that i already added this interceptor when i openSession

Comment: Please open a new question with the code how you install the interceptor (and when) and how you get the session when you want to use it.

Comment: I already did this, i just another question i will appreciate your help... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127366/hibernate-persistencecontext-session-flush