# Hibernate PersistenceContext session Flush

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session

i want to know when does hibernate fulshes the context session when i call session= session.getCurrentSession()

The thing is i have 2 methods in my dao calling getCurrentSession(), when i process the update making the call to getCurrentSession() the entitys are empty:

```
SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];...)
```

How can i make this entitys persist from the select method to the update method?

Here are my methods:

```
public List<SystemConfiguration> getListConfigurations() {
    List<SystemConfiguration> lista = new ArrayList<SystemConfiguration>();
    Session session = null;
    Query query = null;

    String sql = "from SystemConfiguration where description = :desc";
    try {
        /* BEFORE
            session = SessionFactoryUtil.getInstance().getCurrentSession(); 
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Transaction ta = session.beginTransaction(); */
            //FOLLOWING LINE SOLVED THE PROBLEM
            session = SessionFactoryUtil.getInstance().openSession();
        query = session.createQuery(sql);

        query.setString("desc", "configuracion");
        lista = query.list();

        return lista;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}


public void updateConfigurations(List<SystemConfiguration> configs) throws Exception{
        Session sess = null;
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
                    //BEFORE
            //sess = SessionFactoryUtil.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
                    //FOLLOWING LINE SOLVED THE PROBLEM
                 sess = SessionFactoryUtil.getInstance().openSession(new SystemConfigurationInterceptor());
            tx = sess.beginTransaction();
            for (SystemConfiguration sys : configs) {
                    sess.update(sys);   
            }
            tx.commit();
        } // try
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
                tx.rollback();
            } // if
            throw e;
        } 
    }
```

And this is my interceptor:

```
public class SystemConfigurationInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
            private int updates;
        private int creates;
        private int loads;
        public void onDelete(Object entity,
                             Serializable id,
                             Object[] state,
                             String[] propertyNames,
                             Type[] types) {
            // do nothing
        }

        // This method is called when Entity object gets updated.
        public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity,
                                    Serializable id,
                                    Object[] currentState,
                                    Object[] previousState,
                                    String[] propertyNames,
                                    Type[] types) {

            if ( entity instanceof SystemConfiguration ) {
                updates++;
                for ( int i=0; i < propertyNames.length; i++ ) {
                    if ( "updated_at".equals( propertyNames[i] ) ) {
                        currentState[i] =  new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onLoad(Object entity,
                              Serializable id,
                              Object[] state,
                              String[] propertyNames,
                              Type[] types) {
            if ( entity instanceof SystemConfiguration ) {
                loads++;
            }
            return false;
        }

     // This method is called when Entity object gets created.
        public boolean onSave(Object entity,
                              Serializable id,
                              Object[] state,
                              String[] propertyNames,
                              Type[] types) {

            if ( entity instanceof SystemConfiguration ) {
                creates++;
                for ( int i=0; i<propertyNames.length; i++ ) {
                    if ( "updated_at".equals( propertyNames[i] ) ) {
                        state[i] = new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) {
            if ( tx.wasCommitted() ) {
                System.out.println("Creations: " + creates + ", Updates: " + updates +", Loads: " + loads);
            }
            updates=0;
            creates=0;
            loads=0;
        }
```

Comment: Didn't really understand your question, but using session's default flush mode (`AUTO`), the session is flushed when:
1) transaction.commit is called
2) A query is being executed

Comment: Is there any way to make the entitys to persist? i mean not to be flushed after a query is executed?

Comment: My point is i make a select, it returns a List which then i process it and after that i update it to the DB, my problem is that hibernate is marking all the entitys as dirty because there is nothing in the persistanceContext of the session

Comment: I solved it! i dont know why it works but i changed both methods to .openSession() and now everything works fine (the entitys now still in the session it is not auto-flushed), i will update the post with the solution. But now, can someone tell me why openning 2 new sessions make the objects or entitys persist from one to another?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate will flush when you tell it to and when the current transaction is "closed" (usually when the DB connection is returned to the pool somehow).

So the answer to your question depends on which framework you use. With Spring, the session is flushed when the outermost `@Transactional` method returns.

Your "solution" above will not work for long since it never closes the session. While it returns a result, it will leak a database connection so after a few calls, you will run out of connections.

Also your question doesn't really make sense. `SELECT` doesn't change objects, so they don't need to be "persisted" before you change them.

After changing them in `updateConfigurations()`, Hibernate can chose not to write them into the database immediately and just update the cache.

Eventually, if you configured everything correctly, Spring will commit the transaction and that will flush the cache. But when you use Spring, you should never create open and close sessions because it will mess with what Spring is doing.

Comment: Your explanation is really good, but how can I avoid this leak ?, the point is that i want the objects I selected in getListConfigurations() to stay in the session (hibernate cache) and then when i call updateConfigurations() hibernate will be able to compare with its cache and this will result in 1 update and not 100 (implying my selected list contains 100 objects)

Comment: Because I only modify one object of my list, so im expecting that hibernate looks in its cache which object i modified and then update only this one

Comment: The objects are dirty since they are from another session. For such objects, Hibernate makes no assumptions. You need to start a transaction, get all objects, modify them accordingly and then commit the transaction.

Comment: This seems to be helpful, i will search how to do it and try it, after that i will update you thanks again!

Comment: Unfortanely i still cant find the way to make it work as expected... if you have any suggestions with the code i will appreciate it. Thanks.